# add greek letters in inline R code R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was trying to do like this: `qchisq(1-$\alpha$, k-1)`, but the $\alpha$ does not show up in PDF output. I wonder if someone could make the $\alpha$ show up in the PDF output.

What I really want is like this:

[greek letter in R command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNK1v.png)

Comment: You passed `$\alpha$` as an argument of the r function `qchisq`. This should rise an error. Do you just want to calculate `k` and then pint α=5?

Comment: Thanks for your response; I am sorry that I did not put my questions clearly: what I meant is that ` `qchisq(1-$\alpha$, k-1)` ` , the command within two ticks. When it is `knit` to either html or pfd, the verbatim shows up; I cannot get the greek letter  α.

Answer (score 0):

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "10/7/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

qchisq(1 - $\alpha$, k-1)
```

[image]

But this is just text, this is not a calculation funtion like @danlooo suggested, you would have to calculate the number in R, but then you can display the output in Rmarkdown

Comment: Thanks for your response; I am sorry that I did not put my questions clearly: what I meant is that ` `qchisq(1-$\alpha$, k-1)` ` , the command within two ticks. When it is `knit` to either html or pfd, the verbatim shows up; I cannot get the greek letter  α.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with an idea. Just tick the non "-$\alpha$" part:

```
`qchisq(1 -` $\alpha$`, k-1)`
```

It turns out not that bad:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTzd0.png)